# Running Chicken Scheme in emacs

Tags: emacs, scheme, chicken-scheme

I am new to emacs and cannot figure out how to run [Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org) through emacs. From the Chicken Scheme [Wiki](http://wiki.call-cc.org/emacs#cluck) I came across a solution -- using cluck. So, I followed the directions in the `cluck.el` file and added`(require 'cluck)` to my `.emacs` file.

However, emacs can not load the `.emacs` file because it cannot open cluck. Here is the error message given by emacs:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/s2s2/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, cluck

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

This [link](https://github.com/ddp/cluck/blob/master/cluck.el) will take you to the `cluck` file on github.
I think the problem with `cluck` is that I need the other files which it requires... Where would I get these.

1. How can I run chicken scheme through emacs using `cluck`?
2. Once emacs will read `cluck` what is the command to run the chicken scheme interpreter (csi) through emacs?
3. How would I use the `--debug-init` option if I am actually using [Aquamacs Emacs](http://aquamacs.org)?

If you need more information, let me know. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You can start Aquamacs in debug mode by running this command from a terminal window: `/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Aquamacs --debug-init`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd>, type `load-path` and press Enter. Emacs will print the paths from where it loads .el files. If the directory where your `cluck.el` resides isn't there, add it with the following line in your initialization file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/cluck/")
```

This assumes you have your Cluck files inside `~/.emacs.d/cluck/`